# OpenDJ identity mapper for Simple LDAP Bind?

Tags: opendj

As I learned from developer guide, SASL supports identity mapper.

But I can not find an example of simple bind that uses identity mapper.

Does opendj supports that ?

An ldapsearch example would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Identity Mappers are meant for operations (such as SASL Bind) that use a userId or an Authorization ID and not a Distinguished Name (DN).
LDAP Simple Bind requires a DN and a password and thus doesn't need an identity mapper.
I know of one product that allows to authenticate with an email address instead of the user DN, but it's a violation of the LDAP protocol.